# Rounding off float value to one value after decimal

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a code where I have a float value like 29.8888 and when i do as:-

```
float value=29.8888
NSLog(@"value=%0.2f",value);
```

I got 29.8 that is perfectly fine now i want to assign this value in another float variable.I dont know how to do this please help

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float roundedValue = round(2.0f * number) / 2.0f;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1]; 
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];  
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]]; 
[formatter release];
```

I found this, this should be self explaining.
Another, easy and cheap way:

```
float f = 29.8888; 
int i = f *10; // 298 
float answer = i/10.0f; //29.8
```

Comment: last line probably should be float answer = i/10.0f; otherwise integer division will be performed

Comment: @Vladimir excuse me, type it without thinking through! Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score -1):

```
float z = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", value, nil] floatValue];
```